# Question on Proposition 17.5 in John Lee's Smooth Manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

Here is the proposition, for reference: Let ${M_j}$ be a countable collection of smooth $n$-manifolds with or without boundary, and let $M=∐_j M_j$. For each $p$, the inclusion maps $\iota_j :M_j ↪M$ induce an isomorphism from $H_p^{dR}(M)$ to the direct product space $∏_j H_p^{dR}(M_j)$.

I have two questions: why do they have to be countable? This is never used or mentioned in the proof. Also, why is it from $H_p^{dR}(M)$ to $∏_j H_p^{dR}(M_j)$? Shouldn't it be the other way around? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by definition, a smooth manifold has to be 2nd countable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just to clarify: $M_j$ being a countable collection is necessary to ensure that $M$ is countable, and thus smooth, right?

Comment: Yes. If given an uncountable collection, their disjoint union won't be technically a manifold. And dropping the countability condition in the definition will lead to other problems, such as the long line which is not equipped with any Riemannian metric. Anyway, it's just a technical condition.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!